# Change Sorting Of WooCommerce Processing List (To Status Change Date, Not Date Ordered)

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

We have an ecommerce site which only accepts EFT/Bank Transfers. The problem is that we want to ship our items based off when payment is received and not when the order is made. When you go to the Processing list in Woocommerce it sorts the items by their order date but not by the date the status was changed.

Ideally we'd like it to sort in a way that it shows processing items based off the date/time it was changed to Processing, not the date of the order.

That way we can simply run from the end of the list forward and ship based off who has paid first and not who ordered first.

Comment: You could do this directly (new sorting method is automatically displayed when loading the page) or provide an extra column (date modified), which you can then sort with a mouse click. What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't been able to try add any functions myself. I'm the webmaster for the site, but have been tasked to get this resolved with the lack of a dev. I was hoping someone may already have a function written that does this. Ideally when one clicks on the "processing" list, that list would be sorted by default by the date it's status was changed.